# How can I test that Browser tooltip is shown?

Tags: laravel-dusk

**What do I have**:

Laravel 5.5
Laravel Dusk 2.0.14

How can I test (assert) that browser tooltip
[image]
was shown, when I'm trying to submit a form without filling `required` field?

**What I've tried**:

```
$browser
    ->assertSee('Please fill out this field');
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the message with JavaScript:

```php
$message = $browser->script("return document.querySelector('input[name=foo]').validationMessage")[0];
$this->assertEquals('Please fill out this field.', $message);
```

Note that the message will always be set as long as the input's value is invalid. This assertion also works *before* you press the submit button.

Comment: It's working fine on text field, but not on select option, u have any idea how to fix?

Comment: @MarkKhor Please submit a new question.